# CSS and Flexbox layout issue

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Created a codepen at http://codepen.io/cbireddy/pen/vmYxbz

```css
.board {
      display: flex;
      width: 600px;
      height: 400px;
      justify-content: flex-start;
      flex-flow: row wrap;
    }
    
    .square {
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      border: 5px solid black;
      border-radius: 10px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="=board">
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
  </div>
```

I was thinking the squares should be in a 2x3 matrix. Instead they are all stacked vertically. What am I missing? Thought that display: flex will align the items along main axis, which is horizontal.

Can someone please look into this and tell me what am I doing wrong? Goal is to visualize the squares in a 2x3 matrix.

-Thanks
Chakri

Comment: You have typo `class="=board"`

Comment: Thank you, not sure how I missed that. Good catch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to fix the typo and add `box-sizing: border-box` to `.square` so that the borders don't push beyond the defined width.

```css
.board {
  display: flex;
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.square {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="board">
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In row 24 of your HTML (in Codepen), you have typo. Just change `<div class="=board">`to `<div class="board">`

Answer (score 1):

```html
<div class="=board">
```

Replace this with

```html
<div class="board">
```

Should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Try This code

```css
.board {
  display: flex;
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.square {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="board">
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
</div>
```